# get process back to screen

Tags: command-line, bash, python, process, background-process

I was in a screen session with a python script running in the background.
I terminated the screen with the exit command so when I check with

```
screen -ls
```

there are no sockets and with

```
jobs
```

I can see that the script is also not running in the session.
But as i can see with htop for example the script is still a process.
Here is the corresponding line of

```
ps -aux | grep python
```

`username   3012950 99.8  0.8 101140 70524 ?        R    Feb16 1749:20 python3 ./radius.py 2000`

Is there a way to put this process back to were it was, in a screen session?
Or in general take it back from where ever it is now back to the 'normal' background or foreground?

Comment: Hello, how did you push that process in the background?

Comment: I started the script with `./radius.py 2000 &` and then terminated the screen with the exit command.

Comment: You could try this: [How do I attach a terminal to a detached process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31824/201297). But, IMO, *screen* and *tmux* are designed just for this purpose - just detach the session instead of exit it.

Comment: I actually terminated the screen with the exit command by accident because i was in an ssh session. But I got curious where the process went. ^^